# codeigniter and cpanel installation

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-routing

I am completely new to moving codeigniter to my web-server and im having trouble with the configuration. Where do I place my codeigniter project folder in www under myurl.com in in the very root directory? Am i supposed to move out the application and system folders?

I am trying to remove index.php? from my URL name where do i place my .htaccess file in the root or in the same folder as my codeigniter directory?

I wish to be able to type in (www.myurl.com) and be redirected to my home_controller/index
is this possible?

[image]

*below is my .htaccess file in it's entirety*

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /MMSFL/


#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]


#Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>


ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

### I have also made the following changes in config/routes

```
    $config['index_page'] = "";
    $config['base_url'] = "http://myurl.com/";
    $config['server_root'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
    $config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';

$route['default_controller'] = "home_controller";
```

Comment: public html folder you should put your project folder.no need to remove any folder.set basepath in config

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Directory structure**

If at all possible, it's advised that you keep your `system` and `application` folders above the web root. Your `index.php` file needs to be accessible from a browser, so that should go in your `public_html` folder. Here's a possible directory structure that you could use:

```
-/home/edd
    -public_html
        -index.html
        -.htaccess
    -system
    -application
```

You can rename your system and application folders, or create another sub-directory to put them in, if you want.

---

**index.php**

Within `index.php` you'll need to update `$system_path` and `$application_folder` to reflect the location and name of your system and application folders. You can use an absolute path or a relative path. Relative path shown below:

```
$system_path = '../../system';
$application_folder = '../../application';
```

---

**.htaccess**

The first two sections of your `.htaccess` file are there to prevent a user from accessing your system and application folders. If you're storing them above the web root then you don't really need this. If you keep them, then you need to update the paths. This file should be located in your `public_html` folder.

---

**application/config/config.php**

As you've already correctly done, the `index.php` value should be removed from the `index_page` config, so *index.php* can be removed from your url using your *.htaccess* file;

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

should be changed to:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

You may also have to make this change:

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

(If you have no luck with this value, try the others. One should work!)

---

**application/config/routes.php**

```
$route['default_controller'] = "home_controller";
```

(Assuming that is the name of your controller.)

---

Your site is likely to depend on some *assets*, such as CSS and JavaScript. These should go in your web root - `public_html`. You can organise these file however you like.

Answer (score 0):

Move all the files that reside inside your CI-folder into `public_html`. The `.htaccess` file should be located in the root of `public_html`(where application, system, index.php etc also reside).

Side note: don't put `$config` values in `/config/routes.php` - those need to be in `/config/config.php`