# Moving codeigniter project from localhost to cpanel

Tags: codeigniter, cpanel

I am trying to run my codeigniter website on the server.But I don't have a clue that what settings should I perform.

I find the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12282450/codeigniter-and-cpanel-installation) to move the files and do the specified settings but still its not showing me the home page of my website.

Here's what I've done till now.

I moved the codeigniter website's `application and system` folder on the root directory while my `.htaccess` file along with my `assets` and `index.php`  is inside public_html.

Here's my directory structure.

```
-/home/mysite
    -public_html
        -index.php        <-- the path for system is set to '/home/mysite/system' and for application folder is '/home/mysite/application'
        -.htaccess
    -system
    -application
```

I've performed the following settings as mentioned in the link.

```
$config['index_page'] = "";
$config['base_url'] = "http://myurl.com/";
$config['server_root'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';

$route['default_controller'] = "home_controller";
```

Here's my `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Now I don't know why my home page is still not appearing when I enter the url to my site.

Comment: What is currently appearing? An error? A blank page?

Comment: a blank page is appearing right now

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the error log (access from your cpanel)?

Comment: The error log is empty no errors there.

Comment: OK. Try manually specifying your document root (instead of using _SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], and remove the default controller route as mentioned in the link, as it might be overwriting your existing routes, and could be why you're not seeeing anything.

Comment: I set the `defualt_controller` route to empty and specified the `server_root` manually. It gives me the following error. `Unable to determine what should be displayed. A default route has not been specified in the routing file.` and it also gives me this error ` Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/gagsterz/public_html/index.php:2)` in the core/common.php file

Comment: Put the default route back, it's the index.php route in the config file that gets removed. CI needs a default route...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

upload your application folder, system folder, assets folder, index.php, .HTACCESS inside your public_html folder

Answer (score 0):

You need to do few steps:

- update 'application/config/config.php' for `base_url`
- update 'htaccess' file for `RewriteBase` (if needed)
- update file permission (if needed)
- update 'aplication/config/database.php' for `database` settings
- if still you face issue, then you need to debug like:
- print something in index controller and walk through along the function sequence called and then views.

Answer (score 0):

I've ben sturggling with the same and it turned out to be pretty easy than I thought.

Just rename the public folder to public_html folder and upload to server overwriting the existing public_html folder.

That worked for me without doing any changes.