# Codeigniter Deployment Issues

Tags: php, codeigniter, cpanel

I am trying to deploy a code igniter application using cpanel.

I followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12282450/codeigniter-and-cpanel-installation).

I have been able to put up the files on the server as par the instruction in the above link.

The issue now is that i keep getting a **Directory Access is forbidden** error every time i go up the server.

Here's my cpanel directory structure.

Directory Image

[image]

Comment: By default , it will not allow to list the files. from the image i can understand that you didn't move the files. once you moved try to access the page with ip or domain name.

Please post details information

Comment: place the code    i.e.  Options +FollowSymLinks  on top of .htaccess, it's configuation issues

Comment: I moved the files.
My *.htaccess* is in the public html folder and my app's project *system* and *application* folders are in the main folder as shown in the picture.

Comment: Kool-Mind:
Could you be a little more clear?

Comment: @FadilOlamyyWahab is this solved ??

Comment: No,it has not been solved.